# How do you upload files directly to S3 over SSL?

Tags: post, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've been using browser based direct POST uploads with Amazon S3 for a while, and just recently wanted to start posting through HTTPS. Normal HTTP posts work just fine. However, when I post the same form to https://s3.amazonaws.com/, I get a "405 Method Not Allowed".

Do browser based direct AWS POST uploads not support HTTPS? If they do, how can I do it without getting a 405 error?

Thanks!

Comment: The real question is how you do that over http without bloody ssl :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be some problem with your HTML FORM action.

```
The action specifies the URL that processes the request, which must be set to the URL of the
bucket. For example, if the name of your bucket is "johnsmith", the URL 
is "http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/".
```

Please check this AMAZON S3 documentation link for more detail:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTFormDeclaration

There is also a another post on this.
[Amazon S3 - HTTPS/SSL - Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048236/amazon-s3-https-ssl-is-it-possible)

**UPDATE:** 
I was able to upload objects to S3 bucket over SSL using this HTML & Policy.Check the form action.

Policy :

```
{
  "expiration": "2012-06-04T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "<YourBucketName>" },
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    ["eq", "$key", "testImage.jpg"],
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"],
  ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://s3.amazonaws.com/<YourBucketName>/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="testImage.jpg" />
<input type="text" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="text" name="content-type" value="image/jpeg" />
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<YOUR ACCESS KEY>" />
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<YOUR GENERATED POLICY>" />
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<YOUR GENERATED SIGNATURE>" />
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You must know how to generate encoded policy and signature.

Comment: If you specify an HTTPS url with a custom bucket, it will throw an SSL error, so that's not an option unfortunately.

Comment: I succeeded in with HTTPS url with custom bucket. like https://s3.amazonaws.com/<YourBucketName>/. Check update on my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to check the source of the library I'm using to see how it's generating the signature.

Comment: My library was incorrectly setting the form action to *just* https://s3.amazonaws.com/. I manually set it and it works just fine. Thank you!