# How to Configure SSL for Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, bucket

I am using an Amazon S3 bucket for uploading and downloading of data using my .NET application. Now my question is: I want to access my S3 bucket using SSL. Is it possible to implement SSL for an Amazon s3 bucket?

Comment: Might help: [Implementing SSL on Amazon S3 Static Websites](https://knightlab.northwestern.edu/2015/05/21/implementing-ssl-on-amazon-s3-static-websites)

Answer (score 154):

You can access your files via SSL like this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/images/logo.gif
```

If you use a custom domain for your bucket, you can use S3 and CloudFront together with your own SSL certificate (or generate a free one via Amazon Certificate Manager): http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can use bucket names without dots: https://this-is-my-awesome-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com Amazon has a wildcard certificate. Since you can't use dots, you can't have a CNAME domain pointing to your bucket.

Comment: watch out for bucket names containing periods! the SSL won't work on iOS devices but will work just fine in Chrome. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048236/amazon-s3-https-ssl-is-it-possible

Comment: Amazon CloudFront will do this for you.

Comment: @Docunext the problem is that a bucket name without dot makes it hard to use a custom DNS domain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714351/amazon-s3-using-dns-alias-to-bucket-https-at-the-same-time

Comment: To have dot notation bucket names (so you can use Route 53 alias) and you want to PUT objects in via REST, ensure the hostname matches the region. For example, my bucket is in `us-west-2` so the hostname is actually `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` otherwise you get an error.

Comment: without cloudfront can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 27):

Custom domain SSL certs were just added today for $600/cert/month. Sign up for your invite below:
http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

**Update**: SNI customer provided certs [are now available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#cnames-and-https-switch-dedicated-to-sni) for no additional charge. Much cheaper than $600/mo, and with XP nearly killed off, it should work well for most use cases.

@skalee AWS has a mechanism for achieving what the poster asks for, "implement SSL for an Amazon s3 bucket", it's called `CloudFront`. I'm reading "implement" as "use my SSL certs," not "just put an S on the HTTP URL which I'm sure the OP could have surmised.

Since CloudFront costs exactly the same as S3 ($0.12/GB), but has a ton of additional features  around SSL AND allows you to add your own SNI cert at no additional cost, it's the obvious fix for "implementing SSL" on your domain.

Comment: CloudFront is not S3.

Comment: @skalee Correct, but if you want to access it via a domain with custom SSL certs, as the OP requests, you can set up custom CNAME SSL certs that this way and access it through CF.

Comment: For the time being, I've set up two CNAMEs: static-s3 and static-cf, the first one pointing straight to my S3, the second to CF.  First can not support SSL, second can, but it's CF and not S3 as skalee points out.  That's the best I think we can do as of now.

Comment: WOW I guess they have to make up for increasingly cheaper storage costs somehow. at least it's prorated though. if you only use your SSL certificate for 1 hour in a month it's only $20 ;-)

Comment: I meant to say one day

Comment: @Simon_Weaver one day of continuous use, or one day of user's requesting/connecting? I'm confused as to why it's so much money.

Comment: @Elegant.Scripting if you have a dedicated SSL certificate (not a SNI certificate) then that machine needs a dedicated IP which incurs costs. presumably a dedicated IP is needed for you for every location around the world where S3 is hosting your data. So that adds up. But I think it is mainly just that post people don't need it and they can jack the price up for those who do. If you don't need to support IE6 then you should be OK with SNI certificate under CloudFront.

Answer (score 13):

I found you can do this easily via the Cloud Flare service.

Set up a bucket, enable webhosting on the bucket and point the desired CNAME to that endpoint via Cloudflare... and pay for the service of course... but $5-$20 VS $600 is much easier to stomach.

Full detail here:
https://www.engaging.io/easy-way-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket-via-cloudflare/

Comment: Try my guide here: https://www.engaging.io/easy-way-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket-via-cloudflare/

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible directly with S3, but you can create a Cloud Front distribution from you bucket. Then go to certificate manager and request a certificate. Amazon gives them for free. Ones you have successfully confirmed the certification, assign it to your Cloud Front distribution. Also remember to set the rule to re-direct http to https.

I'm hosting couple of static websites on Amazon S3, like my personal website to which I have assigned the SSL certificate as they have the Cloud Front distribution.

Comment: and how did you assign the domain name?

Comment: First go to the certificate manager and request a new certificate. Add your domain there and also include subdomains there, if necessary. Doesn't really hurt anything to put subdomains there, so might as well just put example.com and *.example.com there.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need it, consider redirections.

For example, on request to `assets.my-domain.example.com/path/to/file` you could perform a 301 or 302 redirection to `my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file` or `s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/path/to/file` (please remember that in the first case `my-bucket-name` cannot contain any dots, otherwise it won't match `*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com` stated in S3 certificate).

Not tested, but I believe it would work.  I see few gotchas, however.

The first one is pretty obvious, an additional request to get this redirection.  And I doubt you could use redirection server provided by your domain name registrar — you'd have to upload proper certificate there somehow — so you have to use your own server for this.

The second one is that you can have urls with your domain name in page source code, but when for example user opens the pic in separate tab, then address bar will display the target url.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think this could cause CORS problems.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you cannot create free certificates for S3 buckets. However, you can create Cloud Front distribution and then assign the certificate for the Cloud Front instead. You request the certificate for your domain and then just assign it to the Cloud Front distribution in the Cloud Front settings. I've used this method to serve static websites via SSL as well as serve static files.

For static website creation Amazon is the go to place. It is really affordable to get a static website with SSL.

Comment: For everybody who gets here using google: Remember to create your AWS certificate (also) in the N. Virginia region. Otherwise you wont be able to select it in your CF distribution

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way to add DNS/SSL to an Amazon S3 bucket, is to use CloudFlare workers!

I found this juicy little nugget which did the trick.
https://fershad.com/writing/proxy-aws-s3-content-cloudflare-workers/

Note, use the correct region in the hostname (i.e. us-west-1, us-west-2).

Done and done!

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event))
})

async function handleRequest(event) {
  let requestFolder = '/files'
  let s3Folder = '/'
  
  let url = new URL(event.request.url)
  const cache = caches.default

  let origPathname = url.pathname
  const filename = url.toString().split('/').pop()

  url.hostname = 'bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
  url.pathname = origPathname.replace(new RegExp('^'+escapeRegExp(requestFolder)), s3Folder)

  response = await fetch(url)
  response = new Response(response.body, { ...response})

  return response;
}

function escapeRegExp(string) {  
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\\/]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be Done using **Nginx** and **CertBot** like as bellow:

**Step 1:** Install [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) and [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to your server instance like (Ec2 or any third party)

**Step 2:** Create on file inside Nginx configuration directory

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/your_file_name.conf

With following content

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subkeyword.yourdomain.com;

location / {

    proxy_pass http://your_bucket_name.s3-website.your_region.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

**Step 3:** Execute following command to create certificate for your subdomain

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d subkeyword.yourdomain.com
```

Note: `A record should be there for server IP in your domain hosted zone`