# AFNetworking / AFAmazonS3Client Amazon file uploading

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I get the following error, while trying to upload a file to Amazon using AFNetworking / AFAmazonS3Client

```
s3Client = [[AFAmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:@"mykey" secret:@"mysecretkey"];
s3Client.bucket = @"media.mysite.com";

[s3Client postObjectWithFile:video.assetPath destinationPath:@"/media/videos/" parameters:nil progress:

 ^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite){

     DLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100));
 }

                     success:^(id responseobject){

                         DLog(@"Success");
                         [self deleteAsset:video];

                     }failure:^(NSError* error){

                          DLog(@"Failed %@", error);
                         [self updateVideoAsset:video.assetID key:@"uploadStatus" value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ESUploadNotStarted]];
                     }];
```

The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “media.myserver.com.s3.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk

how to get around this

Thanks
Tonku

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some problems in the AWS SDK for iOS (older versions) that could cause this problem: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=248288

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles onto this: Use a bucket name without periods in it (e.g. `media-mysite-com`). That way, Amazon's wildcard SSL certificate will still apply, and you'll avoid the error.

See e.g. [How to Configure SSL for Amazon S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201316/how-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket#comment23030824_11203685)