# HTTPS Redirects With Website in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have the following setup:

- A documentation website hosted in an S3 bucket
- A CloudFront distribution using that bucket as its origin, accepting HTTP or HTTPS traffic
- 3 custom domain names registered through Route 53; let's call them `example.com`, `.net`, and `.org`.
- An ACM certificate for those 3 domains so HTTPS will work
- The example.com Hosted Zone has an ALIAS record pointing to the CloudFront distribution, so `http://docs.example.com` or `https://docs.example.com` will show the website.

Now, I want to put the following redirect rules in place.  Basically, everything should redirect to docs.example.com, using whatever protocol the user originally requested with.

1. `http://docs.example.net` > `http://docs.example.com`
2. `https://docs.example.net` > `https://docs.example.com`
3. `http://docs.example.org` > `http://docs.example.com`
4. `https://docs.example.org` > `https://docs.example.com`

This is where I'm having trouble.  If I point the `.net` and `.org` subdomains at the CloudFront distribution with ALIAS records, then the URL will still show that subdomain, rather than `.com`.  If I create S3 buckets named after the `.net` and `.org` subdomains with redirect rules to the `.com`, and add ALIAS records to those buckets, then everything works great for HTTP, but HTTPS fails b/c the ACM certificate only works for CloudFront, not S3.  And if I try to just add CNAME records to the `.net` and `.org` subdomains that point to `.com` then HTTPS still fails, and also HTTP redirects to HTTPS for some reason.

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201316/how-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket), it looks like my only option is to create two additional CloudFront distributions, one for `.net` and one for `.org`.  But that just sounds *so* over-engineered to me, and will really bloat the CloudFormation template that I'm using to do all of this.

**Can anyone recommend a simpler solution?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct approach in CF to redirect across domains (Even though .com .org and .net linked to same distribution). The simplest approach I could recommend is to use [AWS Edge Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) in Cloudfront to redirect accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That link is broken though!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. Corrected the link.