# Error retrieving audio from s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I am attempting to write my first Alexa skill. After much research, I have built a skill that plays a musical note.

When I test the skill, I get the following error message:

```
Error: There was a problem when trying to retrieve the audio from https://s3.amazonaws.com/music-notes/A-sharp.mp3
```

I can access the file just fine in my browser and I believe I have enabled CORS. Can someone point me to  the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the docs it had stated to use 16,000 Hz at 48 kbps, but when I did that on audacity, I left the bit rate mode at average. Changing this to constant fixed the problem. Thanks to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKlnpf0SsoE for telling me this.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this is a SSL issue, but I haven't investigated it.

If it is, this link might help:

[How to Configure SSL for Amazon S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201316/how-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket)

Comment: I can't imagine how, but I tried putting <audio src=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/music-notes/A-sharp.mp3\" /> into the voice simulator and hit listen. It gave me: Error: A URL must be between 9 and 2000 characters.

Comment: That's because you removed the protocol: `https://` 

If you add it back in, you should see:

`Mixed Content: The page at <your website> This content should also be served over HTTPS.` This shows that it's a HTTPS issue.

Also, you should be able to replace the protocol with just `//`

Comment: For some reason, the http got removed when I pasted the tag. The real tag has the http:// and it is still returning the same error. It must be security on stackoverflow's part.

Comment: paste inside a code block by using backticks to not have it remove elements

Comment: I just tried putting 
`<audio src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/music-notes/A-sharp.mp3">` in a plain `http` based website, and it loaded without an issue. 

If you're trying to load this from a `https` website, you will get the mixed origin error. 

I do not get your error about the URL character length, that's new to me.