# Using SSL on Amazon S3 bucket with CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So currently I have a CNAME mapped to my Amazon S3 bucket so that I can access my files like subdomain.domain.com/file.js

The problem is SSL doesn't work on this.

Now I could add Cloudfront, however, that creates a cache for the files and the files need to update dynamically.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Possibly look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201316/how-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront is a complementary service to S3, and is the only way AWS provides to combine a custom domain name and SSL with an S3 bucket.

If you really don't want CloudFront to cache any content, you can set the Minimum, Default, and Maximum TTL to 0.

Comment: Cool, so basically use Cloudfront, but don't cache any content with it.

Comment: Right.  CloudFront can do a number of useful things, many of which don't involve caching.