# Is it possible to host a secured static website without registered domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https

I want to host a static website in AWS S3.

Can I enable HTTPS, without buying a domain name?
I have a site, and in all the tutorials it requires a domain name.

Answer (score 4):

Although there's some discussion in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201316/how-to-configure-ssl-for-amazon-s3-bucket) suggesting that you may access files directly via S3 HTTPS URL, [official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html) recommends the use of **CloudFront** for S3 static website endpoints:

> **Note** The Amazon S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPS.

If you don't want to buy a domain, just keep CloudFront's default. It will look like `d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net`.
In case you change your mind and want to set up a custom domain, [follow the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html).

For the CloudFront configuration, follow the following steps, as described in this [premium support blog page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/):

> 1. Open the CloudFront console.
> 2. Choose **Create Distribution**.
> 3. Under **Web**, choose **Get Started**.
> 4. For **Origin Domain Name**, you can either choose your S3 bucket's REST API endpoint from the drop-down menu, or you can enter your S3 bucket's website endpoint. For more information, see [Key Differences Between the Amazon Website and the REST API Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff)
> 5. For **Viewer Protocol Policy**, choose HTTP and HTTPS.
>      **Note**: Choosing **HTTPS Only** blocks all HTTP requests.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

As S3 URLs do not support HTTPs so you need to use another layer, which can be AWS CDN i.e. [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

AWS suggests to use Cloudfront if you want to add HTTPs support for your static website hosted on S3. Please follow the steps mentioned here

[How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)

> 1. Open the CloudFront console.
> 2. Choose Create Distribution.
> 3. Under Web, choose Get Started.
> 4. For Origin Domain Name, you can either choose your S3 bucket's REST
>      API endpoint from the drop-down menu, or you can enter your S3
>      bucket's website endpoint. For more information, see Key Differences
>      Between the Amazon Website and the REST API Endpoint.
> 5. For Viewer Protocol Policy, choose HTTP and HTTPS.
>      **Note**: Choosing HTTPS Only blocks all HTTP requests.
>
> If you're not using a custom domain with CloudFront, choose Create
>   Distribution to complete the process. If you are using a custom
>   domain, follow these additional steps before you create the
>   distribution:
>
> 1. For Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs), type your custom domain.
> 2. For SSL Certificate, choose Custom SSL Certificate. Then, choose the
>      custom SSL certificate to assign to the distribution.
>      **Note**: For more information on installing a certificate, see How do I install SSL/TLS certificates on Amazon CloudFront?
> 3. Choose Create Distribution.
>      **Note**: After you choose Create Distribution, it can take about 20 minutes for your distribution to deploy.