# Amazon S3 Bucket naming convention causes conflict with certificate

Tags: amazon-s3

I renamed an Amazon S3 Bucket from:
"multi-word-name"

to what Amazon suggests as being the best naming convention:
"multi.word.name"

The problem is that this causes a problem with the SSL certificate:
"You attempted to reach multi.word.name.s3.amazonaws.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.s3.amazonaws.com ..."

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What's the context/scope of your question, i.e. programming environment/language?

Comment: is a good question (hit this myself) but probably best on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two potential issues involved with bucket naming in [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

### DNS compliant bucket naming and SSL verification in general

First and foremost, there is a huge and severely under documented caveat in place still regarding the suggested DNS compliant bucket name convention, see [Virtual Hosting of Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html):

> When using virtual hosted-style buckets with SSL, **the SSL wild card certificate only matches buckets that do not contain periods**. To work around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification logic. *[emphasis mine]*

- So from this perspective your desired approach simply won't work - this problem is explored in more detail in Kerry's answer to [Amazon S3 - HTTPS/SSL - Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057349/45773), which features a dedicated answer regarding this problem from [AWS Support](http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/) as well.

### DNS compliant bucket naming and SSL verification within the AWS SDK

In case you are asking from a context/scope around the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), you might want to try again with the new [AWS SDK for Java 1.4.0](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/2425068307485737), which features related *Changes to S3 host name SSL verification*:

> The Amazon S3 client is now less strict when validating host names, when using DNS-style bucket addressing (the default). **Now any domain ending in s3.amazonaws.com will bypass the strict SSL checking requirements**. This change fixes issues experienced by customers in non-US regions using buckets with periods in the name. *[emphasis mine]*

Please note that this change has been released just yesterday and I haven't explored either its background or its relation to the aforementioned generic restriction yet, but it might help you on your way.

Good luck!