# Error when uploading file with fineuploader using the "no server-side code" approach

Tags: amazon-s3

To upload files to S3, I'm following the tutorial at http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/01/15/uploads-without-any-server-code/

I got the first few errors out of the way, but i'm stuck at this one.

> Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid.
>   You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “videoupload.mobdesignapps.fr.s3.amazonaws.com” which could put your
>   confidential information at risk.

I'm hosting the site on S3 and need to upload files to another S3 buckets.

Any clue appreciated

Comment: This is not a Fine Uploader issue. It looks like you have not setup your static S3-hosted website properly for access over SSL. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719764/https-for-amazon-s3-static-website for more information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this question: [Amazon S3 Bucket naming convention causes conflict with certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344272/amazon-s3-bucket-naming-convention-causes-conflict-with-certificate)

Essentially bucket name need to not contain any period (".") to work with the default S3 SSL certificate.