# carrierwave authenticated_urls and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I want to use `fog_authenticated_url_expiration`

```
 def fog_public
    false
  end
```

It works great, however because of S3's issue with subdomains and dots (.) in bucket names. My path has SSL warnings and I can't change the bucket name to be otherwise to keep my routes working correctly.

[Amazon S3 - HTTPS/SSL - Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048236/amazon-s3-https-ssl-is-it-possible)

The default carrierwave path for authenticated urls produces SSL warnings because of the subdomain:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/quiz/131/question_sheet/Q286.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOSTQ6UXXLEWIUQ&Signature=xdHUEiNjEZxftVxr5rw7uHaMmwk%3D&Expires=1387662760
```

Whereas this formula would work fine:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/subdomain.domain.com/uploads/quiz/131/question_sheet/Q286.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOSTQ6UXXLEWIUQ&Signature=xdHUEiNjEZxftVxr5rw7uHaMmwk%3D&Expires=1387662760
```

How can I override the path style in carrierwave to use the second one to avoid SSL issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this myself and there is now a work around if you're using a recent version of carrier wave using path_style when setting the fog_credentials.

See this post here:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1076

But this should solve it.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider => 'AWS', path_style: true
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'subdomain.domain.com' # required
  config.asset_host   = 'https://subdomain.domain.com'            # optional, defaults to nil

  config.fog_public     = true                                # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```