# domain -> cloudfront -> s3 (https) bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up a domain name with Route53 + Cloudfront + S3 bucket.

Also created a certificate in Cloudfront, and sometimes it was working sometimes.

Now I get `AccessDenied` from my bucket. It seems to be that:

https://not.working.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/           (not working)

http://not.working.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/            (working)

https://not.working.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/index.html (working)

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/not.working            (not working)

Maybe the it's simple, but I googled arround trying everything. Strange thing is that at somepoint in was working. Cloudfront has a destribution time, so its hard to debug.

Comment: I now Use error pages, redirecting in cloudfront to index.html. It's a solution, and you dont see it in the browser. But its not clean..

Comment: If your bucket name contains a `.` character then the S3 SSL certificate will not work. See this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048236/amazon-s3-https-ssl-is-it-possible Note that all the example URLs in your question are going straight to S3, bypassing CloudFront, since they are not using your custom domain but simply the default S3 domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple. I didn't set the root object in cloudfront

Default Root Object -> index.html

But s3 and cloudfront are strange...

I was only posting the S3 problem because it was strange it didnt work over https sometimes....